# Pink ball in cricket

Tags: cricket

In recent day- night cricket match between AUS&NZ played by pink ball. In Day-Night cricket match the game played by pink ball, so what is the difference in specification in the pink ball.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specifications of a cricket ball are covered in [Law 5](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-5-the-ball/), and are the same for all varieties of cricket (ODI, T20, tests etc)

The colour used is a matter of regulation, so the ODI regs specify a white ball, the tests a red ball etc. Therefore a ball that is red in colour is identical in specification to a pink or white one, just the outer leather covering is dyed a different colour.

Answer (score 2):

The pink and red balls are almost identical. The major difference is between white ball used in ODIs and red balls used in Tests.

From a batsman's perspective, there are hardly any big differences. A red ball is easier to see against a light background, such as during the day, which is the main reason why they continue to be used in day-only matches. White balls are easier to see against dark backgrounds, such as at night, hence why they are used in day-night matches. Whereas, in case of day-night test matches, the ball is painted pink for easier visibility through the twilight and to preserve the natural wear of the ball.

For bowlers, there aren't any major documented differences, though I'm sure there are slight differences between the different paints used that can effect the ball later on in an innings. That said, consistency between the different types of balls has always been a goal when developing them, so this is unlikely to be a major issue.

The main difference between the pink and the red ball is that a very fine film of extra color of paint is added to the surface of the ball and then the clear cellulose finishes lacquer finishes over the red and pink ball are put.

Comment: Could you add some references for the items you mention please?

Comment: reference-
http://www.abc.net.au/news/2015-10-27/sixteen-shades-of-pink/6889650

Answer (score -1):

The specifications of red/white/pink or any other official ball used in a match are same.
But the difference lies in behaviour.

Pink balls deteriorate more slowly than white balls, but have better night visibility than red balls, making them the most suitable ball for day-night Test cricket.

During trials, players have noted that the pink ball goes soft quickly, and stops swinging early, both of which lead to a holding pattern in which runs are scored slowly and few wickets taken.

The pink ball is closer to the red ball than its one-day equivalent white ball.
The subtle changes relate to how the leather is dyed and the protective film that is added to preserve the pink colour.

With the red, the top coat does scuff off within the first 10 to 15 overs and then the natural fats of the ball are what encourage the later shining. This feature is still possible with the pink ball, however it is harder to shine. This will mean that teams will need to work hard at preserving the condition of the ball.

Comment: Could you provide some references for the statements you've made in this answer?